# How to use async function without Hooks in React Native

Tags: node.js, react-native, sockets

I am currently developing an React Native app that involves realtime chatting feature.

The goal is to have a `socket.js` that will export default a `socket`.

(Initializing socket this way is the best in my opinion as it can ensure that `io('xxx')` only run once)

I want the socket to be created with a `userToken` that I stored in my `EncryptedStorage` and this means involving async await function.

(Creating `socket` like this because I will need the `userToken` to match the `socket.id` and put them both into a JSON in my server side)

`socket.js`

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
import BASE_URL from "../screens/BASE_URL";
import EncryptedStorage from 'react-native-encrypted-storage'

async function get_token() {
  return await EncryptedStorage.getItem('userToken')
}

export default socket = io(`${BASE_URL}`, {
  transports: ['websocket'],
  extraHeaders: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${await get_token()}`
  }
})
```

Using this code made the Authorization header in my server side shows `Bearer [object Object]` instead of the real user token

(I am confident that the server side code is working fine because before I added the userToken in, it was able to receive the connection)

### What I have tried

I tried turning the socket into a function, something like this:

```
export default async function socket(){
  return io(`${BASE_URL}`, {
    transports: ['websocket'],
    extraHeaders: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${await get_token()}`
    }
  })
}
```

But now the socket won't even get connected to my socket.io server.

I also tried something like

```
export default socket = io(`${BASE_URL}`, {
  transports: ['websocket'],
  extraHeaders: {
    Authorization: `Bearer `
  }
});

get_token().then(token => {
  socket.extraHeaders.Authorization += token;
});
```

But it just skips the `get_token()` function and proceed to export my `socket`

Will appreciate any help and/or suggestion provided. Thank you!

Comment: The last attempt seems to  be really close. What if you did `const socket = io(....)`, then do the `getToken().then(token=>{...})` and add `export default socket`?

Comment: @PhantomSpooks It almost worked! Now it is showing an ```Unhandled Promise Rejection``` of ```You attempted to set the key `Authorization` with the value `"Bearer xxx"` on an object that is meant to be immutable and has been frozen.```

Comment: I somehow got it work with the similar concept. In the ```getToken().then()```, I put an ```socket.emit('update_authorization', {...})``` and send my token as data. Then in my server side I can then update the ```socket.handshake.headers.authorization``` to that data. It worked. But I wonder whether this is the best practice. Either way thanks alot @PhantomSpooks